# Where is defined what the name of my organizationalUnit should be?

Tags: ldap, openldap

Should my organizationalUnit for user accounts be named "users" or "people"?
To narrow the possible answers in the first place, is there any institution that defined that?

Follow-up question: Should we differentiate between people and users to take a scenario into account where we want to provide information about people who do not have a user account on a connected system?

Comment: I would argue that OU's (except for maybe some technical limitations) can be assigned any arbitrary name and you can create as many OU's and sublevels as you need to fit your organisations needs with regards to creating order and delegation of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a required distinction between ou=Users and ou=People:
Because the objectclass person from the core.schema and the objectclass account from the cosine.schema are both structural, no DIT entry can contain two structural classes at the same time.
When a DIT needs to contain a uid (unique identifier like a username; attribute provided by account objectclass) and an email address (mail attribute provided by inetOrgPerson objectclass) there have to be two entries for one user.
Therefore you are likely to put account entries under ou=Users and person entries under ou=People.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your company's use case. What I have found to be effective is to separate OUs based on type of user. For example, we have an OU for 'Employees', 'Contractors', 'Students' and another OU for 'Service Accounts'.

Really, at some point in the future you'll need to query, organize or do something with particular groups of accounts. If you're too granular, it'll be overwhelming, if you're to broad, it'll be useless.

Comment: You're basically right. Here I'm using this installation as a centralized authentification information hub for connected applications. The provided identity information is not intended to be used as OS accounts. Therefore I wonder whether ou=Users comes from the posixAccount background or is arbitrary even though it's used widely in PAM with LDAP documentation. I couldn't find any information where ou=People comes from.